# App doesn't call didSelectRowAtIndexPath in TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am trying to use a TableView to select an item, but if I tap the item nothing happens. I already have tried to fix it with all answers to the other questions on this topic.
Can somebody help me?

Here my code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Working")
    let eventItem = eventItems![indexPath.row] as! Event
    (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! QRCodeViewController).selectedIDfunc(eventItem.id as! Int)
}
```

Comment: have you set the `.delegate`-property of the tableView?

Comment: @FelixSFD how do i set it?

Comment: Assuming that `self.tableView` is your `UITableView`, put `tableView.delegate = self` in your `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: tableView.delegate = whateverImplementsTheDelegateProtocol

Comment: Either within the storyboard (Ctrl+click) on your tableview drag to your ViewController and choose `Delegate`. Or in code in your ViewController `tableView.delegate = self` (where tableView is an attribute of your ViewController) in your `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: Thank you it worked